# Failed to build a basic template, which consists of a header, a sidebar and a page content

Tags: primeng, angular12

I'm new to PrimeNG and I'm trying to get started with a basic template, which consists of a header, a sidebar and a page content.

[image]

As you can see on the image, everything is so messed up. The menu doesn't really take the entire left side and the page content is being randomly placed. Not even to mention that this is not what I expect. If you look at [PrimeNG's official grid example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-primeflex-gridsystem-demo?file=src/app/app.module.ts), it should look something like:

[image]

## [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x7gyez?file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html)

Comment: I updated the question to draw more attention